# I cannot install Facebook C# SDK on VS2010 in Windows Azure Solution

Tags: c#, facebook, sdk, azure, installation

I created a Windows Azure Solution with a Web Role Project, a work role and a WCF role.
I tried to install a the FB C# SDK 6.0.20 dated 5/31/2012
I got this result:

Successfully installed 'Facebook 6.0.20'.
Successfully uninstalled 'Facebook 6.0.20'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Failed to add reference to 'Facebook'.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to download the command line tool (CLT) of NuGet and downloaded/installed the packages manually.
The packages download at the same directory where you run the CLT. Then I just added references to the web role project. It worked and it compiles right.
Hope this helps some other developers.